# Linking to other discussion rooms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, chat

There should be some simple way to link to another discussion room. Also normal links to discussion rooms should be displayed in some special fashion. Currently links to other rooms look like plain link: [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/…](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18/sandbox)

Comment: I completely agree. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: That's not exactly true -- room links get special treatment (it displays the room name as a link and adds the room description). That's not exactly pretty though, and there's lots more information that can be added, I agree with you on that.

Comment: Linking does not work specially if the message has also other text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an answer to remove this question from unanswered view.